# How can I mix output images from two different methods in C#?

Tags: c#, image, list

I have a problem as follow,

I have an application based on C# which has two lines of image production:

Line-1 generates a series of frames per second based on some mathematical calculation. Each frame (image) is consist of black and white pixels which they form a pattern.

Line-2 is generating another series of frames which are made based on random noise generator. So they are just different frames which contain only noise!
Now, my question is I need to mix this frames from these two lines together randomly. By meaning that, for example I need to select 5 frames from line-1 and 3 frames from line-2 and so on mixing them together randomly. This mixing procedure will change randomly.

My own solution is if I store images from line-1 production in a separate list, and line-2 production in another list so I can have a flag to select from these two lists randomly. But as a fact that this images are generating real time I don’t know if that solution works or not. Does anyone have any alternative solution for my question?;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use queues (`Queue(T)` or `ConcurrentQueue(T)`) to store the images. Assuming you use a thread to fill each queue and one to consume from both queues.

Example:

```
  private ConcurrentQueue<Bitmap> line1 = new ConcurrentQueue<Bitmap>();
  private ConcurrentQueue<Bitmap> line2 = new ConcurrentQueue<Bitmap>();
  private Random randomGenerator = new Random();

  //thread 1
  private void FillLine1()
  {
     //your line 1 image producation code
     Bitmap yourCalculatedBitmap = new Bitmap(100,100);
     line1.Enqueue(yourCalculatedBitmap);
  }

  //thread 2
  private void FillLine2()
  {
     //your line 2 image production code
     Bitmap yourCalculatedBitmap = new Bitmap(100,100);
     line1.Enqueue(yourCalculatedBitmap);
  }

  //thread 3
  private Bitmap RandomImageSelection()
  {
     Bitmap image;

     if (randomGenerator.Next(2) == 0 && line1.TryDequeue(out image))
     {
        return image;
     }

     if (line2.TryDequeue(out image))
     {
        return image;
     }

     return null;
  }
```

Comment: thank yo for your comment, may i ask you by "/*bitmap*/" in "line1.Enqueue(/*bitmap*/);"?

Comment: also why you have put 2 as value inside the bracket?

Comment: `/*bitmap*/` is just a placeholder. There you would add your created bitmap to the queue. `randomGenerator.Next(2)` produces either 0 or 1. So this code takes about 50 percent of the images from line1 and the rest from line2.

Comment: is "image" my final output? you mean if i put " pictureBox1.Image = image;" is it going to display images from two lines randomly?

Comment: _is "image" my final output?_ You define that. But I think it should work but I'm not really an export in windows forms. Addition: -> When you set the picture you have to be on the UI thread.

Comment: "ConcurrentQueue" is giving me error, do i need to add any reference?

Comment: Yes. You need `System.Collections.Concurrent`

Comment: its giving me error, i have put the code inside my button but doesn't work;(

Comment: What kind of error do you get? Could you update your question and post the code which is not working?

Comment: its basically for this line:"line1.Enqueue(/*bitmap*/);", Error-1-No overload for method 'Enqueue' takes 0 arguments

Comment: should i put anything instead of /*bitmap*/?

Comment: @user3384676 Yes! It's just a placeholder/comment to show you where you should put your calculated bitmap. See the updated answer.