# How can I get output results from my Queue<T> in C#?

Tags: c#, image, queue

I have two threads which they generate a series of images separately. Each thread called “line-1” and “line-2”.

I am using the following code to mix the outputs of other two threads randomly with each other. However I was expecting to get series output images from this thread, but it does not give me any output.

```
    //thread 3
    private Bitmap RandomImageSelection()
    {
        Bitmap image;

        if (randomGenerator.Next(2) == 0 && line1.TryDequeue(out image))
        {
            return image;
        }

        if (line2.TryDequeue(out image))
        {
            return image;
        }

        pictureBox3.Image = image;

        return null;
    }
```

Can anyone tell me on how to get a series of images from this thread-3 from the queue to my pictureBox3?

Comment: You will probably need to supply more code about how the threads are started to get a useful reply.  It is likely that the queue's with images are not yet populated, therefore, you cannot dequeue anything.  So you have no image.

Comment: You should reformulate. How to set your picturebox?

Comment: "RandomImageSelection" should probably be in some sort of loop that terminates when both threads are done. Also, you would need some sort of sleep so you could see the image.

Comment: The code from other duplicate question looked better - single queue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22484394/how-can-i-mix-the-output-of-two-different-threads-in-c instead of 2 queues

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22484394/how-can-i-mix-the-output-of-two-different-threads-in-c/22484506#22484506 ?

Comment: As an aside, this is a classic Consumer/Producer problem. Make sure you solve that before trying to get the randomization to work.

Comment: So you want 2 queues which another thread picks of one or the other? I can repaste my code with that change too.

Comment: BlueM; i think you are right, let me repeat my requirement again, i need two queues that another thread picks the elements from two queues randomly and present the output results somewhere.

Comment: BlueM; sorry for so many question :) i just wanted to double check if you changed your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code returns without assigning to picturebox. It will always assign null to Picturebox. Maybe you should rewrite it:

```
private Bitmap RandomImageSelection()
{
    Bitmap image = null;

    if (randomGenerator.Next(2) == 0 && !line1.TryDequeue(out image))
    {
        line2.TryDequeue(out image)
    }

    if (image != null) 
    {
        pictureBox3.Invoke(new Action(() => pictureBox3.Image = image));
    }

    return image;
}
```

In this case it will pick from line2 if line1 is empty, so it will drain line2.

Edit: Added invoke code as this probably doesn't execute in an UI thread.

Comment: BlueM; thank you for your comment;) this line is giving me error "if (image != null) ", Error-1-Use of unassigned local variable 'image'

Comment: Just assign null to bitmap in initializer. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting image to your picture box

```
  Bitmap image;
  if ((randomGenerator.Next(2) == 0)? line1:line2).TryDequeue(out image))
  {
     pictureBox3.Image = image;
     return image;
  }
  return null;
```